# Checking if integer JavaScript forms

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have begun learning javascript and I cannot get the security code part of my form (and I have yet to fix the other things such as card number) to bring up an alert if they have not entered 3 integers, I can get it to alert if the person doesnt enter 3 ints/strings/symbols etc... but > or < 3. However I cannot get it to alert the user if the things they pass are not integers. Thank you!.

edit: so the issue im trying to solve is how to run my is_int function on the theForm.cvs.value im sorry if im unclear its all a bit messy.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

    function is_int(value){ 
        if((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)){
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;
        } 
    };

    function verification(theForm) {
        content = "";
        var cardLen = (theForm.cardLength.value).length;
        var securitycode = new is_int(theForm.cvs.value);

            if (cardLen !== 16) {
                content += "Please make sure you've entered 16 digits.";
            }
            if ((theForm.userName.value).length === 0) {
                content += "Please make sure you've entered the correct name.";
            }
            if ((theForm.month.value) < 1 || theForm.month.value > 12 || theForm.month.value === "" || theForm.month.value === "MM") {
                content += "Please make sure the you've entered the correct month.";
            }
            if ((theForm.year.value) < 2016 || ((theForm.year.value) === "" )) {
                content += "Please make sure you've entered the correct expiry year.";
            }
            if ( !securitycode || ( (theForm.cvs.value).length !== 3) ) {
                content += "Please make sure you've entered the correct security code.";
            }
            if (!content == "") {
                alert (content); return false;
            }
        };

</script>



</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><h1>Checkout:</h1></center>

    <div style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:200px;">

        <form name="myForm" class="theForm" onSubmit="return verification(this)" >

        Card Number: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Expiration:
    <br>
        <input type="text" name="cardLength"> <input type="text" name="month" style="width:30px" value="MM"> - <input type="text" name="year" style="width:30px" value="YY">
    <br>
        Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Security Code:
    <br>
        <input type="text" name="userName"> <input type="text" name="cvs" style="width:30px">
    <br>


    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a regular expression to check `theForm.cvs.value` -- something like `^\d{3}$` which will check for a value that has three and only three digit characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to create a `new` `is_int`. New creates an instance of an object and calls its constructor, but you just need to get a return value from a function.

```
if ( !is_int(theForm.cvs.value) || theForm.cvs.value.length !== 3 ) {
    content += "Please make sure you've entered the correct security code.";
}
```

Comment: perfect!, I cant believe I didnt try this before, thank you!